# Angular - Refreshing mat-table from array change

Tags: angular, typescript, mat-table

I have an app call watcher, composed of a component / service.
I have a simple table which shows empty properly

```
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="this.getWatcherTable()" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  
        ... my columns and rows are described here

    </table>
```

The source is linked to my component file

```
export class WatcherComponent{

    constructor(public watcherService : WatcherService ) {}

    getWatcherTable(){
        return this.watcherService.watcherTable;
    }
}
```

Itself linked to the service file

```
export class WatcherService {
    watcherTable : Array<Watcher> = new Array();

    updateWatchers(name,value){
        this.watcherTable.push({name:name, value:value});
    }
}
```

The update is trigger by another app and works well, a console log of the array have the update, but the array is still displayed empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you update an array you should create new one so Angular change detection will update automatically component.  So instead:

```js
export class WatcherService {
    watcherTable : Array<Watcher> = new Array();

    updateWatchers(name,value){
        this.watcherTable.push({name:name, value:value});
    }
}
```

You should have:

```js
export class WatcherService {
    watcherTable : Array<Watcher> = new Array();

    updateWatchers(name,value){
        this.watcherTable = this.watcherTable.concat([{name:name, value:value}]);
    }
}
```